# Select rows with maximum value from select result

Tags: sql, select

I want to select rows with max vallues from the following select, but result table name is wrong in subquery (`select max(result.Sum) from result`):

```
select *
from 
(select sum(Rooms.n_seats) as 'Sum', DepKinds.title
from Rooms join Departments on Rooms.department = Departments.id
join DepKinds on Departments.kind = DepKinds.id group by DepKinds.title) result where result.Sum = (select max(result.Sum) from result);
```

So how to select maximum sum and title for those sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use the `result` alias behind `FROM` in the subquery. Try to use `HAVING`.

```
select sum(Rooms.n_seats) as 'Sum', DepKinds.title
from Rooms 
join Departments on Rooms.department = Departments.id
join DepKinds on Departments.kind = DepKinds.id 
group by DepKinds.title
having sum(Rooms.n_seats) >= all
(
   select sum(Rooms.n_seats) 
   from Rooms 
   join Departments on Rooms.department = Departments.id
   join DepKinds on Departments.kind = DepKinds.id 
   group by DepKinds.title   
)
```

This will return **all** `DepKinds.title` having a maximum number of seats.